# Get new rotation degree and center position

Tags: ios, transform

I have an application written in Flash and export a description file to describe the image position and rotation. The rotation AXIS is the lefttop of the object.

Then, I like to read the description file and draw those images inside iPhone using Object-C. Since iPhone's rotation uses object Center as the AXIS, I like to convert the lefttop X,Y and also the rotation degree based on lefttop to the rotation degree based on the center, and get the center X, Y.

And, I like to convert it back to lefttop based rotation degree and lefttop X, Y in case I like to use Flash to recreate what user did in iPhone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can move the rotation axis for views on the iPhone to the top left corner by importing the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework, and then setting

```
view.layer.anchor = CGPoint(0,0);
```

Comment: Inside iPhone, I still like to use center as the Axis. The only thing I want is a Math formula that can convert the number for one time.

Comment: should be view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);

Comment: (0, 0) is the bottom left corner of the bounds rect, (1, 1) is the top right corner but by defaults it's set to (0.5f, 0.5f)